# Can Visual Studio 2010's Schema Compare feature be configured to default to 'Non Skip Objects'?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, schema-compare

I find that in almost every case, I change the filter of the schema compare results pane to 'Non Skip Objects' so that I see only those objects that have changed. Is there any way for this filter to be set as the default (rather than 'All')?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appear to be the default in [SQL Server Data Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/tools.aspx). Note that although this is a pretty good alternative to the original Database Project, it is still missing Data Compare.

Answer (score 1):

I think your out of luck.  After looking for about 20 minutes I couldn't find anything.